# How To Store a Dungeon Map

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using AS3, but general programming wisdom unspecific to AS3 is great too!

I am creating my first game, a top-down dungeon crawler with tile-based navigation, and I am deciding how to store my maps.  I need to be able to access a specific tile at any point in time.  My only thought so far is to use nested Vectors or Arrays with the first level being the row and the second being the column, something like this:

```
private var map:Array = new Array(Array(0,1,0,0,1,1,0),Array(0,1,0,1,0,1,0));
private var row2col3:uint = map[1][2];

/*map would display as such:*/
#|##||#
#|#|#|#
```

Ultimately, the idea is to build a Map class that will be easily extensible and, again, allow free access to any specific tile.  I am looking for help in determining an effective/efficient design architecture for that Map class.

Thanks!

Comment: I just recently did a 12 hour coding challenge to make a tile based level editor that reads and writes new levels. It's fairly basic, but handles a lot of these issues fairly well. If you want, I have no qualms with open sourcing the project for you and the general public to access. Anyway, I'll have some time to post an answer with details on the steps I took and why later tonight (CST).

Comment: That would be great, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Also you might want to adjust your question asking what would be a logical design or architecture to use in developing a "map" class that is extensible and provides relief to large array mangement (seeing as how it was already down voted).

Comment: I will take your advice right now.  Sorry, but what do you mean by relief?  Just that it's "more convenient than" large array management?

Comment: I just mean that it gives a solution to storing/accessing a large array for tiles. Might make more sense when you see my answer later.

Comment: Actually a public 2D array/vector is what you just need to implement, and you are already halfway there. I see that there are now helpful tips in the answers, you can derive from them easily enough. About what to store in the deepest layer, an int or an object, this depends on whether you need to have more than static maze layout (say you want there be chests, so if you want to store the loot together with the maze, you either get another array just for loot, or store an `Object` in the array and give it properties for loot. If you don't, having a "chest" integer value in the maze is enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments I would upload and give my source code for a 12 hour challenge project to create a tile based level editor. The source code can be found at: [GitHub BKYeates](https://github.com/BKYeates/AS3editor)

This level editor focuses on textures being a power of 2, and uses blitting for drawing on all the textures. It can read, write, and store partial tiles. There is also some functionality to erase and draw on collision boxes.

Now in regards to how the storage should be setup, it is really up to you. If you are going to be storing lots of information I recommend using Vectors. Vectors perform faster than most other container types except for `ByteArray` (if used correctly). In my level editor I used a `Vector` with a particular setup.

The `Vector` I used named `_map` in a class called `tilemodel`. `tilemodel` is responsible for updating all the storage information when a change is made. The _map variable is setup like so:

```
_map = new Vector.<Vector.<Vector.<Object>>>();
```

This is a pretty heavily nested `Vector` and in the end stores, can you believe it, an `Object`! Which admittedly really chunks out the performance gains you get from using `Vector` when you are indexing the furthest nested elements.

But ignore that because the indexing gain from this setup is really key. The reason it is setup this way is because I can reference a layer, a row, and a column to grab a specific tile object. For example, I have a tile on layer 2 in row 12 column 13 that I want to access:

```
var tileObject:Object = _map[2][12][13];
```

That works perfectly for pretty much any scenario I could use in my tile based game, and the speed is comparatively better than that of a `Object` or `Dictionary` when this is being accessed multiple times (i.e. - in a loop which happens often).

The level editor is designed to use all blitting and leave onus to my management classes for storage. The speed gain from doing this is very high, and the way it is currently setup the `tilemodel` can store partial bitmaps making it slightly more flexible than your standard rigidness of a power of 2 texture reader.

Feel free to look through the source code. But here is a summary of what some of the classes do:

- `tilecontroller` - Issues state changes and updates to tilemanager and tilemodel
- `tilemanager` - Responsible for texture drawing and removal.
- `tilemodel` - Stores and updates the current map on state changes.
- `r_loader` - Loads all assets from assetList.txt (paths set to images
  there).
- `hudcontroller` - Currently this was the last thing I was working on, lets you draw on collision boxes that are stored in a separate file alongside the map.
- `g_global` & `g_keys` - Global constants and static methods use
  ubiquitously
- `LevelEditor` - Main class, also designed as "View" class ( see MVC pattern: [MVC Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_view_controller) )

Also as I've mentioned it can read back all the storage. The class used for that I did not upload to GitHub, but figured I would show the important method here:

```
    //@param assets needs to be the list of loaded bitmap images
    public function generateMap( assets:* ):void {
        var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData( g_global.stageWidth, g_global.stageHeight, true, 0 );
        _canvas = new Bitmap( bmd, "auto", true );
        _mapLayer.addChild( _canvas );
        _canvas.bitmapData.unlock();

        g_global.echo( "generating map" );

        var i:int, j:int, m:int;
        for ( m = 0; m < _tiles.length; m++ ) {
            for ( i = 0; i < _tiles[m].length; i++ ) {
                for ( j = 0; j < _tiles[m][i].length; j++ ) {
                    //wondering why im type casting in this evaluation?  _tiles[i][j].tile == int( _tiles[i][j].tile ) 
                    //the level editor stores tiles that are larger than the grid size at indices containing values that are a percent of the tile size
                    var tile:Object = _tiles[m][i][j];
                    if ( tile != null && int( tile.tile ) == tile.tile ) {
                        addTile( g_global.GRIDSIZE * tile.column, g_global.GRIDSIZE * tile.row, { index:tile.tile, bitmap:assets[ tile.tile ] }, tile.rotation );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        _canvas.bitmapData.lock();
    }
```

Anyway I hope this information finds you well. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry I'm just now responding!  Thanks a million for this, and you confirmed all my instincts on how to go about this.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question a while back: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/60433/is-it-more-efficient-to-store-my-tile-grid-as-a-dictionary-or-an-array.  I'm not sure that it would really matter whether it's an Array or a Vector (the differences in efficiency seem to differ between FP versions, etc.).

But, yeah, you probably want to use one or the other (not a Dictionary or anything), and you probably want to index it like `[y * width + x]`, not `[x][y]`.  Reasons: Efficiency and not having overly complicated data structures.

Also if you need to be able to regularly access the Array or Vector outside of that class, just make the variable internal or public or whatever; making it private and wrapping over it with functions, while being more prim-and-proper class design, would still be overkill.

Answer (score 0):

One method I am using right now for my own thing is that I'm storing my tiles in a black and white pixel bitmap (and wrote a wrapper around that). I'm not sure how efficient this is overall as I've never benchmarked it and just wrote it quickly to create a map for testing purposes, but I am finding that it does offer an advantage in that I can draw my maps in an image editor and view them easily while still allowing random pixel/tile access.

Looking at your sample code, I'm guessing you have only two types of tiles right now, so you could just use black and white pixels as well if you want to try it.

I've done the 2d array method as well (using it still actually for other parts) which works fine too, but perhaps can be harder to visualise at larger sizes. Looking forward to Bennett's answer.

Comment: I've thought about possibly creating an inner-platform effect where you essentially just feed in a string to some function that parses each character in the string and creates the level from it.

Comment: interestingly, this was what I did before to start...just have a long string of 0s and 1s in a text file.